# Using jQuery replaceWith() with HTML Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I am attempting to replace a div class with a different one based on the content of an HTML select. Unfortunately, the following code doesn't seem to be working.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("answerDropdown").change(function() {
          var val = $(this).selectedValues();
          if (val != '') {
            $("filler").replaceWith('<div id="replaced"> Replaced. </div>');
          }
      });
  });
  </script>

 <select id="answerDropdown">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>

 <div id="filler">Replace Me!</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`#id` selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) need a `#` prefix and use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get a `<select>` element's value, it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#answerDropdown").change(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (val != '') {
        $("#filler").replaceWith('<div id="replaced"> Replaced. </div>');
      }
  });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/tHruM/).

Answer (score 0):

Id selectors should be used with `#`. You have to use `#filler` for wrapping the div.